# How to expand the output of a truncated list to view more values of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, printing

Is there a specific way to display all the truncated  data values of a list. The displayed values are as follows

```
         v                          w

Row1    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3 .....1.0] [0.1, 0.2, 0.3 .....1.0]
```

Here are the option I tried
Option 1
p

```
 pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
 pd.set_option('display.max_seq_items', None)
 z  = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
```

**Output:
it is still truncated**

Option 2

```
for i, row in z.iterrows():
    for j in row['w']:
        print(j)
```

**Output:
it is stll truncated**
Any help on how to display all the truncated values and display the full list.

Answer (score 0):

You can `print` after conversion [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
print(df.to_string())
```

output:

```
                                                            v                                                        w
Row1  [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
```

Used input:

```
L = list(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1).round(2))
df = pd.DataFrame({'v': [L], 'w': [L]}, index=['Row1'])
```

default `print`:

```
                                                      v  \
Row1  [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, ...   

                                                      w  
Row1  [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, ...
```

Comment: I would like to have it  in a list format so I can plot later on. Is there a way of displaying it without converting it using tostring() @mozway

Comment: Either you want to display, or you want to use the data, you have to chose. If you want to use the data, all the points are here: `df.at['Row1', 'v']`

Comment: I want to have all the values within the list displayed. And I still keep it as a list. Any thoughts @mozway

Comment: If you use `print(df.to_string())` this will display the data as you want and still keep everything as lists.

Comment: Can you please check if this is correct as I am still getting error
z= pd.DataFrame(columns=['v', 'w'])
z = pd.read_csv('r.csv')
print(z['v'].tostring())
When I do this I get attribute error. @mozway Am i doing it right

Comment: If you run `z = pd.read_csv('r.csv')` you overwrite the previous `z= pd.DataFrame(columns=['v', 'w'])`, so if there is no `v` column, it's normal to have an error